# How to set Zeppelin interpreter dependencies via configuration

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to deploy zeppelin 0.7.3 and add ojdbc7.jar and custom jar dependencies automatically.

I'm wondering if there's a configuration item in `zeppelin-env.sh` or `zeppelin-site.xml` that could do this.

example:

copy `zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all` to `/data` and copy `ojdbc7.jar` to `/data/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/jdbc/ojdbc7.jar`

In interpreter, find spark, I can see `dependencies/artifact` added according to the configuration.

`/data/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/interpreter/jdbc/ojdbc7.jar`